# Magento2.4 refused to load all external resources

Tags: magento2.4, content-security-policy

I have a Magento2.4 website and when I view the console I see the below errors. I read about creating a CSP module to whitelist the domain names however it does not seem to work? I do see Mycompany_Cspmodule listed as enabled when I view a list of modules on the command line

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' because it violates the
following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com 
secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com 
www.paypalobjects.com js.braintreegateway.com www.paypal.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.sandbox.paypal.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com www.youtube.com *.payments-amazon.com *.payments-amazon.co.uk *.payments-amazon.co.jp *.payments-amazon.jp *.payments-amazon.it *.payments-amazon.fr *.payments-amazon.es *.avada.io yotpo.com www.yotpo.com p.yotpo.com staticw2.yotpo.com w2.yotpo.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have the website in production mode.
I also have a custom module I thought would fix this but guess am missing something.
I have the following custom module folder and files setup
app/code/Mycompany/Cspmodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <csp>
        <mode>
            <storefront>
                <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
            </storefront>
            <admin>
                <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
            </admin>
        </mode>

    </csp>
</default>
```

app/code/Mycompany/Cspmodule/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

```
 <csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
 <policies>
    <policy id="default-src">
        <values>
            <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
            <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
            <value id="googlemaps" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
            <value id="yotpo" type="host">*.yotpo.com</value>
            <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
        </values>
    </policy>
 </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

app/code/Mycompany/Cspmodule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Austinwilliams_Cspmodule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Mycompany/Cspmodule/registration.php

```
<?php
  use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

  ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Mycompany_Cspmodule', __DIR__);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the correct thing however, the issue is that it tells you in the error it violates `script-src`.
In this case you need to include the offending url in a script-src node in the xml like so;

```
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="srcipt-src">
            <values>
                <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Another issue I can see is you've included the same key twice (`maxcdn` in this case) which you can't do.